# Как правильно использовать HttpClient внутри сервиса?

Tags: веб-программирование, angular2, typescript

Допустим, я хочу скрыть работу с `HttpClient` за сервисом, а затем внедрять его в конкретный компонент и дергать методы, что бы все детали были скрыты от компонента.

Проблема в асинхронности `HttpClient`. Например, я дергаю get и метод пролетает дальше, возавращая `undefined`.

Ну, например, компонент обращается к сервису service.GetCars(), который внутри себя дергает API и шлет get запрос, как мне внутри компонента получить эти данные?

Я должен вернуть Observable, а пользователь данного сервиса выполнить `subscribe` и перемапить данные? Ну это по моему не совсем верно

Comment: вопрос непонятен

Comment: Как правильно дождаться выполнения запроса и вернуть компоненту запрошенные данные, которые затем сможет использовать для отображения

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-json-data

Comment: Ну получается снаружи сабскрайбится...

Comment: вы не приложили ни 1 куска кода, вы хотите чтоб тут гадали на кофейной гуще? :)

Comment: я не понимаю вашего вопроса, `Я должен вернуть Observable, а пользователь данного сервиса выполнить subscribe и перемапить данные? Ну это по моему не совсем верно` - что именно не верно? что перемапить? вы читали документацию по http в angular?

Answer (score -1):

используйте код:

```
this.service.GetData().subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    //res - полученные данные
});
```

код сервиса:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthorizeService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  GetData(){
    return this.http.get('https://localhost:44397/api/GetData');
  }
}
```